# Swipe to refresh Icon is not shown properly

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh, swiperefreshlayout

I am using a `ListView` and refreshing it when swiping down with `SwipeRefresh`, it works fine till here. The problem occurs when I try to set a `TextView` on `mListview.setEmptyView()` the `Refresh Icon` is not shown while swiping.

It looks like it is under the `TextView`. However if I don't put that `TextView` on the same XML it works fine, but I need to show a message when a list is empty. **What is causing this behaviour?**

Here is the layout I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_light"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_light">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mListView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/swipeToRefreshTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/msg_swipe_to_refresh"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Refresh listener:

```
//Listeners
mSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

        //Here I do some job
        beaconScanSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
    }
});
```

Here is where I set the adapter of `ListView` and onEmptyView:

```
//UI
mListLv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mListView);
mSwipeRefresh=(SwipeRefreshLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
swipeToRefreshTv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.swipeToRefreshTextView);

//Set Adapter
mListLv.setAdapter(mBaseAdapter);

//Set Message when list is empty
mListLv.setEmptyView(swipeToRefreshTv);
```

I have tried to move my `TextView` inside `<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` tags or above them. Still same result.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_light"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_light">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/swipeToRefreshTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/msg_swipe_to_refresh"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        //below = swipeToRefreshTextView
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mListView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

please update your layout in this way and check.

Comment: As i have written i tried it above `SwipeRefreshLayout` with `below` on  `<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` also but same behaviour

Comment: please show me your screen: Refresh Icon is not shown while swipping

Comment: Yeah it is not shown while the list is empty and trying to swipe. But when i release the touch the icon comes afterward, Icon should come from `ActionBar` down based on the swipe then when released will be gone

Answer (score 0):

As long as your `SwipeRefreshLayout` and your `TextView` are under same `RelativeLayout` one of them will be on top of each other.

I would try to put it at the same level as your `ListView`, then both of them inside a container, inside `SwipeRefreshLayout`. And since `SwipeRefreshLayout` is the single item in the layout, you can drop the outer `RelativeLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_light"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_light">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mListView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/swipeToRefreshTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/msg_swipe_to_refresh"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: nope same behaviour. THe thing is that while i swipe it is not shown but after i release touching the screen, the icon is shown. 
When the `listView` is populated with data the icon comes from `ActionBar` while i swipe down. I want this behaviour to work same also when the list is empty

Comment: What version of support-v4 library are you using?

Comment: `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` into a `ScrollView`. For me it did the trick.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mListView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```